# Telemetry size for MarkLogic 9

Tags: marklogic-9

We had recently upgraded our 8 host MarkLogic cluster from ML8 to ML9 (9.0-8.2). We enabled telemetry for our cluster and we did see around 1 MB data is getting uploaded to telemetry in ErrorLog.txt. We had a system /tmp space of 5GB but whereas in Memory,Disk, Swap space requirements  (https://docs.marklogic.com/9.0/guide/installation/intro#id_11335) it says 
"System temp space sizing - when using telemetry allow for 20 GB maximum in system temp space, although normal usage will likely be less than 100 MB."
My concern is do we face some performance issues if we didn't increase /tmp to 20 GB?

Comment: If this is for production, I'd recommend matching the written requirements. If not, it depends on how badly you need the Telemetry data. I am not entirely sure how MarkLogic would use /tmp for Telemetry, so can't tell much more. Consider reaching out to Support for more information about this.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. We had raised the case with ml support.